# LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR

Tags: oracle, ldap, kettle

I use Kettle to synchronise from oracle to ldap,but there are somthing wrong at ldap output.
A user with the following structure.
[A user with the following structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vk1G.jpg)

[second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y61ZB.jpg)

Here are the errors
2017/01/17 16:54:43 - Spoon - 正在打开转换 [oracletoldap]...

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - Spoon - 开始执行转换.

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Exception :

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Error inserting for entry with DN = [0002]!

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Invalid name: 0002

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Error inserting for entry with DN = [0002]!

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Invalid name: 0002

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.ldapinput.LDAPConnection.insert(LDAPConnection.java:511)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.ldapoutput.LDAPOutput.processRow(LDAPOutput.java:252)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:50)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Caused by: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: Invalid name: 0002; remaining name '0002'

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at javax.naming.ldap.Rfc2253Parser.doParse(Unknown Source)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at javax.naming.ldap.Rfc2253Parser.parseDn(Unknown Source)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at javax.naming.ldap.LdapName.parse(Unknown Source)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at javax.naming.ldap.LdapName.(Unknown Source)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.addRdnAttributes(Unknown Source)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_createSubcontext(Unknown Source)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_createSubcontext(Unknown Source)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(Unknown Source)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.createSubcontext(Unknown Source)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.createSubcontext(Unknown Source)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.ldapinput.LDAPConnection.insert(LDAPConnection.java:508)

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - LDAP Output 3.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :    ... 3 more

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - Spoon - 转换完成!!

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - oracletoldap - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 错误被检测到!

2017/01/17 16:54:43 - oracletoldap - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 错误被检测到!

Answer (score 0):

0002 is not a proper dn value.  Usually, you have a step like User-Defined-Java-Expression that builds the dn (e.g. dn = "cn=" + cn + ",ou=users,dc=domain,dc=tld") before it is referred to by LDAP-Output.